# I need to access my remote pc using my IP address , so i can control my PC remotly

Tags: networking, ip, remote-desktop, remote-access

I need to access my remote pc using my IP address , so i can control my PC remotly.
Plz help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use VNC (for example tightVNC) or remote desktop. If you have a dynamic IP, you could use DynDns.org to provide a static URL for your IP.